# XYChart.Data getNode() is null

Tags: java, javafx

I try to get node of an `XYChart.Data`, but it is null.

```
var a = new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(10, 10);

if(a.getNode()==null){ System.out.println("true"); }
```

Why `getNode()` return null? What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `XYChart.Data.node` property has an initial value of `null`. If you don't set it yourself then it will be set once the data becomes part of a chart. From [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#nodeProperty) (**emphasis** mine):

> The node to display for this data item. You can either create your own node and set it on the data item before you add the item to the chart. **Otherwise the chart will create a node for you that has the default representation for the chart type. This node will be set as soon as the data is added to the chart.** You can then get it to add mouse listeners etc. Charts will do their best to position and size the node appropriately, for example on a Line or Scatter chart this node will be positioned centered on the data values position. For a bar chart this is positioned and resized as the bar for this data item.

If you need to do something with the default `Node`, you can add a listener to the property (before adding the data to a chart) to be notified of when it becomes non-`null`.

```
data.nodeProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue != null) {
        // do something...
    }
});
```

Or get the `Node` after you've added the data to a chart.